# tts application force closes

Tags: android, text-to-speech

error message
The constructor TextToSpeech(SQLiteExample, SQLiteExample) is undefined
04-16 04:06:19.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1728): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sql.SQLiteExample
error line

```
myTts = new TextToSpeech(this,  this);
```

in onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in error you are not passing right params in `TextToSpeech`.as docs [says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#TextToSpeech%28android.content.Context,%20android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener%29):

```
TextToSpeech (Context context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener)
```

*context* : The context this instance is running in.

*listener*:     The TextToSpeech.OnInitListener that will be called when the TextToSpeech engine has initialized.